# Modifying mvn and redlpoying the code

Tags: google-app-engine, maven

I am working on an open source project and am kind of new to mvn. The project I am working on is https://github.com/bsautner/com.nimbits. They offer a ready to go solution , however I need to edit a few fields here and there. I tried to download  the source and do an mvn install in the jetty directory. However it keeps failing. Whats the best way to build the above project?

Comment: if you post the errors you're getting from maven I can help you.  you may need to run the maven command datanucleus --enhance to run the data nuclues enhancer first. -Ben